# (VSDC) Can you apply a DeLogo filter to an ellipse shape?

Tags: video

I usually use DeLogo under Video Effects/Filter options. Now I am wondering if one can create an Ellipse that has the DeLogo effects applied.

I attempted this by creating an ellipse object and then applying a DeLogo filter. As you can see in the image, only the border of the ellipse seems to have the DeLogo filter applied and not the inner part of the shape.

[image]